# can I trace sub called function with OpenCensus?

Tags: go, trace, jaeger, opencensus

I want to trace the whole project with Opencensus and Jaeger. I added HTTP trace in entry services and add  `stratspan` in middleware surrounded whol my services and this two-span called and show on Jaeger. My problem is each service contain a lot of function and I want see a trace of all my functions but in this way not show overall service not shown each function. I don't like add per function add one `stratspan`. I use `ctx context.Context` entry all my function but not different!

Answer (score 0):

There's really not many options for other than starting a span in each function you'd like to instrument:

```
func something(ctx context.Context) {
  ctx, span := trace.StartSpan(ctx, "something")
  defer span.End()
}
```

If your functions have a common call signature, or you can coalesce your function into a common call signature, you can write a wrapper.  Examples of this can be seen in http ["middleware"](https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/making-and-using-middleware).

Consider the http.Handler, you could write a [decorator](https://www.google.com/search?q=dm03514%20decorators&oq=dm03514%20decorators&aqs=chrome..69i57.1985j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for your functions that handles the span lifecycle:

```
func WithTraced(handler http.Handler, opName string) http.Handler {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ctx, span := trace.StartSpan(ctx, opName)
        defer span.End()
        handler.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))

    }

}
```

A similar pattern could be applied by [embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) structs.

Comment: I used Gokit with the same yo middleware `opencensus.TraceEndpoint('service_name')` of package `github.com/go-kit/kit/tracing/opencensus` this use same your way use middleware surrounded all services functions but just add one span not per function one span!